# find duplicate values in 3 text files in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 text files see following

```
result1.txt
===========
782
778
719

result2.txt
============
130
129
719

result3.txt
============
718
719
585
520
```

I want to upload this files in php with form and after that i want to check how many duplicate values are there in all of the files remember duplicate means all 3 files have the common value is duplicate for e.g. 719 is containing in all files
i try to do with array but it not working with 3 array
i used `array_intersect($array1,$array2,$array3);` but it not works.
can anyone help me ??

## Here is my code

```
$a = file('result1.txt');
$b = file('result2.txt');
$c = file('result3.txt');

foreach($a as $key => $value)
{
$a[$key] = $value;
}

foreach($b as $key => $value)
{
$b[$key] = $value;
}

foreach($c as $key => $value)
{ 
$c[$key] = $value;
}
$result=array_intersect($a,$b,$c);
print_r($result);
foreach(array_intersect($a, $b, $c) as $x) { echo $x; }
```

Comment: How did you build those arrays and what was the result of the `array_intersect()`?

Comment: Please, share you code. Function array_intersect(array1, array2 [,array ...]) exactly does what you need. It compares the values of two or more arrays, and return an array that contains the entries from array1 that are present in array2, array3, and so on.

Comment: if i use array_intersect($a,$b) it works but with $a,$b,$c 3 variable it not works

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$hash = array();

// for each input file
$file = new SplFileObject("input_file_name");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);
while (!$file->eof()) {
    $num = (int) $file->fgets();
    if (!array_key_exists($num, $hash)) {
        $hash[$num] = 1;
    } else {
        $hash[$num] += 1;
    }
}
$file = null;

// now we get only the entries with a count of 3
$triples = array_filter($hash, function ($val) { return $val == 3; });
$results = array_keys($triples);
```

At the end, `$results` will contain the values that occur 3 times in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

`array_intersect()` works fine using the following:

```
<?php
$array1 = [782,778,719];
$array2 = [130,129,719];
$array3 = [718,719,585,520];

$dupes = array_intersect($array1,$array2,$array3);

echo '<pre>',print_r($dupes),'</pre>';
```

Plugging files into the arrays could be accomplished with:

```
$array1 = readfile('result1.txt');
$array2 = readfile('result3.txt');
$array3 = readfile('result3.txt');
```